# Access parent's DOM from script in an iframe in IE Mobile

Tags: javascript, windows-mobile, iframe, ie-mobile

I have a framed window (currently iframe but may possibly be frame) - I do not have control over this.

I would like to detect if my content is inside an iframe (or frame).

I wanted to compare the location of the current document with the one the top object holds but it appears it is the same object (top === window).
After extensive googling I got to this [IEMobile blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/iemobile/archive/2007/05/15/ie-mobile-standards-support.aspx) and in one of the comments there is this answer:

> iemoblog said:
>
> No, you can't access any part of the
>   parent's DOM from script in an iframe
>   in IE Mobile.
>   December 20, 2007 12:12 PM

I can't seem to find any documentation about this - can anyone help confirm this or even better - suggest a way to detect if the page is "framed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I did not get anywhere after finding the comment left in the [IE Mobile blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/iemobile/archive/2007/05/15/ie-mobile-standards-support.aspx) (by Charles Morris - program manager on the IE Mobile team, on his own post) I am forced to add this answer and state it is:

As designed (or a bug at least)

> **prc said**:
>
> regarding iframe support:  I can
>   create an iframe, but am unable to
>   "look outside" the frame.  "top" and
>   "parent" both seem to refer only to
>   the iframe itself and not the topmost
>   ancestor or immediate ancestor as the
>   documentation suggests that it should.
>   Is there a way to refer to javascript
>   variables in the enclosing document
>   from within an iframe?
>
> December 19, 2007 9:29 PM
>
> **iemoblog said**:
>
> No, you can't access any part of the
>   parent's DOM from script in an iframe
>   in IE Mobile.
>
> December 20, 2007 12:12
>   PM

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that if the frame is from a different domain then the container then your JavaScript is sandboxed and can't access the other frame/container.

What you can do is try to compare `window` to `window.top` and the possible outcomes are:
1. The are the same -> you are the top window on the page
2. They are not the same -> you are not the top window on the page, there is some container page, in the same domain as you, that holds your window as a frame or iframe.
3. A security exception is thrown -> you are not the top window on the page, but the top window is from another domain and you can't access it.

maybe something like this:

```
try {
  if (window == window.top)
    return "I'm parent";
  else
    return "I'm a child of " + window.top.location;
} catch (e) {
  return "I'm a child of something from another domain";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it does not work on the iemobile I use to test (samsung omnia).

Comment: what is the problem that you have with this?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to reply. I want to keep my content "un-boxed" in a frame. Running the code provided does not detect the "boxing" of my content in a frame. The code works fine for any other browser.